# cant counting all open files by lsof + lsof is hung

Tags: redhat, kernel, sysctl, lsof, openfire

we are tying to count all open files by lsof

```
lsof | wc -l
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/42/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

but sill after 1 hour lsof not rerun answer ( like its stuck )

any other approach how to count all files ?

we have redhat 7.2 version

- I guess we have also CLOSE_WAIT entries consumes kernel memory

second , we need to found which application is consume most of open files ,

Answer (score 1):

Use `-b` option tells lsof not to use kernel functions that may    block.

You can exclude the `CLOSE_WAIT` sockets using `-iTCP -sTCP:^CLOSE_WAIT`

```
lsof -b -iTCP -sTCP:^CLOSE_WAIT
```